# how to overwrite the row values of dynamically created table on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

I have a drop down from which user can select option like "old","new". According to the selected option i am querying data from xml and displaying it in table.

Html

```
<body>
<table id="NovelList" class="NovelList" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Novel Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Publishing Year</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Purchase</th>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

and for adding data to table on option select i am doing this:-

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.evaluate(pathExpr, xmlDoc, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();
        while (result) {
            var b= [];
            var d=result.childNodes;
            for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++){
                if(d[i].nodeType == 1){
                    b.push(d[i]);
                    }
                }
            for(var p=0;p<b.length;p++){
                    var n = b[p];
                    if (n.localName== "title"){var t = n.childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                            if (n.localName== "author"){var a = n.childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                            if (n.localName== "year"){var y = n.childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                            if (n.localName== "price"){var pr = n.childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                            if (n.localName== "code"){var c = n.childNodes[0].nodeValue;}

                    }
            $('.NovelList tr:last').after(
                    '<tr><td class="value">'+ t
                            + '</td><td class="value">'+ a
                            + '</td><td class="value">' + y
                            + '</td><td class="value">' + pr
                            + '</td><td class="chk"><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value='+'"'+c+'"'+'></td></tr>');
        result = nodes.iterateNext();
        }
    }
```

but as i am using ".after", every time i select an option it is getting appended to the already displayed table.

I want to replace the table rows whenever an option is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help Fenixp. I added header and body tag to the table but then also empty() was not working so i end up using remove().

HTML file after editing

```
<table id="NovelList" class="NovelList" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Novel Title</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Publishing Year</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Purchase</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Calling this before adding row-

```
$('#NovelList tbody >tr.dtr').remove();
```

and adding row using

```
$('.NovelList tbody tr:last').after(
                    '<tr class="dtr"><td class="value">'+ t[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                        + '</td><td class="value">'+ a[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                        + '</td><td class="value">' + y[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                        + '</td><td class="value">' + p[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                        + '</td><td class="chk"><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value='+'"'+code+'"'+'></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, separate your head and body like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then call

```
$('tbody').empty();
```

that should do the trick. Basically, you need to erase the DOM first.

Comment: yes but as empty() method removes all child nodes, the first row of the table having headers also removed by it and nothing displayed.

Comment: @neeti in that case, properly separate header and body - put header in thead tag and body in tbody tag. Then call empty on tbody. Edited answer.